# Stop incessant notifications

Tags: cron, notification, notify-osd

I wanted to schedule a job to run at a specific time just once. So, I used the [at](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/at.1posix.html) command:

```
at now -f /path/to/task.sh
```

Now, in the task script, I wrote code to display notifications using [notify-send](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/notify-send.1.html) in an infinite loop:

```
while true
do
 notify-send "Reminder!!" "Reminder text"
done
```

I did this because I did not want the notification to go away by itself, and thought that I will be able to stop the notifications manually by killing its process.

So, I executed `pkill notify-osd`, but another instance of the process starts as soon as I do this.
I also tried by removing this job from that `at` queue by executing `atrm <job-id>`, but the notifications did not stop.

So, now I have got notifications being displayed continuously displayed on my screen.
**How do I stop it?**

*I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*

Comment: Kill the parent of the most recent `notify-osd` job.

Comment: How do I find its parent?

Comment: Do `ps -ef` and look in the third column, that is the PPID or Parent Process ID.

Comment: Just restart GUI session

Comment: @Jos Its parent was the `atd` job. I killed it but it restarted. Also its parent pid is '1', so I don't think we can kill the parent.

Comment: @Serg Hod to do that?

Comment: Log out then log back in. There's also option to open TTY2 (by pressing CTRL+ALT+F2 ), log in there on the virtual console, and run `sudo service restart lightdm`. Or just shutdown and reboot

Comment: @Serg Thanks, it worked! But is there any way to do without restarting the whole GUI itself?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi I am not quite sure. Killing `notify-osd` should have worked, unless your `notify-osd` has changed. When I installed xubuntu OSD service changed to another one, not Ubuntu's default, so I couldn't kill it, even if I was using the default desktop.   try to run `ps -e | grep -i notify` and see what processes there are

Comment: Killing it works as long as the loop does not run forever. If I change the loop to make it run for 10 times, and I kill `notify-osd` just after running `at`, the notification goes away as expected.

Comment: @Serg Should I add this as an answer ?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi sure, go ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to logout and login back, as mentioned by @Serg in the comments [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699982/stop-infinite-notifications-display/700152#comment1026128_699982).